# Extracting key:values data from json response using .Net NewtonSoft

Tags: .net, json, parsing, json.net, deserialization

I have this small json file that I'd like to parse:

```
{
    "audio_file": {
        "__type": "File",
        "name": "somename.m4a",
        "url": "the_url"
    },
    "createdAt": "2015-07-30T19:37:14.916Z",
    "location": "Somewhere",
    "objectId": "CSHgwDuhg8",
    "updatedAt": "2015-07-30T19:37:14.916Z"
}
```

I'd like a way to access all the values here according to the key. But for some reason I just can't make it..!

I am trying the following:

```
var json = JObject.Parse(rawJson);  
string sjson = json.ToString();

JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(sjson));
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.Value != null)
        Console.WriteLine("Token: {0}, Value: {1}", reader.TokenType, reader.Value);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Token: {0}", reader.TokenType);
};
```

Cheers!

Comment: Do you have a class to deserialize?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Not sure I understand the concept of deserialization :)

Comment: So I did this: 
            var jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(sjson);
And I get the 5 keys and their values, but how can I access one of them? For example, the URL?

Comment: Hmm.....okay, let write answer. Give me 5 mins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serialization is the process of converting an object to such a form which can be stored, passed around between systems and converted back to the object when required. The form can be binary data or text/string (e.g. string representation of the audio file object you have). Read about serialization here in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms233843.aspx) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).

De-serialization is the reverse process of bringing back the object from that serialized binary/string data. Learn about [.Net JSON Serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770(v=vs.110).aspx) and [JSON Deserialization with Newtonsoft Json](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm) here. You are already using it when you do `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`.

Now to deserialize the data you have, you need the class representation that matches the data. If you already have it, then good, otherwise you need to create it.

You can also deserialize to `Dictionary<string, dynamic>` and find the values with the keys, BUT, this is risky as you will not have any compile time type check and if something is wrong with code or data, it will throw runtime exception.

Let me show you some code example.

**Code to json deserialize**

The classes you need

```
public class AudioFileDetails
{
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set;}
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Objectid { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    public FileDetails Audio_File { get; set; }
}

public class FileDetails
{
    public string __Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Method to deserialize with Newtonsoft.Json

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert; //Add Json.NET NuGet package

public class JsonSerializer 
{
    public static T DeserializeData<T>(string jsonData)
    {
        try
        {
            return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonData);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //log exception if required
            return default(T);
        }
    } 
}
```

Now few lines of code to deserialize your data and use internal values

```
var jsonString = @"{'audio_file':{'__type':'File','name':'somename.m4a','url':'the_url'},'createdAt':'2015-07-30T19:37:14.916Z','location':'Somewhere','objectId':'CSHgwDuhg8','updatedAt':'2015-07-30T19:37:14.916Z'}";
var data = JsonSerializer.DeserializeData<AudioFileDetails>(jsonString);
var url = data.Audio_File.Url; //access any property here
```

**Code to deserialize to string,dynamic dictionary**

```
var jsonString = @"{'audio_file':{'__type':'File','name':'somename.m4a','url':'the_url'},'createdAt':'2015-07-30T19:37:14.916Z','location':'Somewhere','objectId':'CSHgwDuhg8','updatedAt':'2015-07-30T19:37:14.916Z'}";
var dictionary = JsonSerializer.DeserializeData<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(jsonString);
//To use, get property with the key. For complex objects, use .PropertyName
var url = dictionary["audio_file"].url;
```

Again, the compiler will not check dynamic at compile time. If anything is wrong, it will fail throw exception at run-time.

Comment: @PavelZagalsky fixed couple of typos, please use this updated code. Also, I've added explanation on how you can also use (but not recommended) the Dictionary<string, dynamic>.

Comment: Ha! Brilliant! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You actually have already deserialized and have everything you need with this line `var json = JObject.Parse(rawJson);`

Here is a method that you could call to get all the data you are after.

```
    static void OutputJObject(JObject jsonObject, string indent = "")
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> node in jsonObject)
        {
            Console.Write(indent);
            if (node.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}", node.Key);
                OutputJObject((JObject)node.Value, indent + "  ");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}, Type: {2}", node.Key, node.Value, node.Value.Type);
            }
        }          
    }
```

Call with `OutputJObject(json);` and you will get the following output.

```
Key: audio_file
  Key: __type, Value: File, Type: String
  Key: name, Value: somename.m4a, Type: String
  Key: url, Value: the_url, Type: String
Key: createdAt, Value: 7/30/2015 19:37:14, Type: Date
Key: location, Value: Somewhere, Type: String
Key: objectId, Value: CSHgwDuhg8, Type: String
Key: updatedAt, Value: 7/30/2015 19:37:14, Type: Date
```

This gives you what you want without having to deal with multiple additional deserialization calls and dealing with dynamics. You also get the plus that you get information on the data type of the value.